# String split function with delimiters in C

Tags: c, string, split

I am having trouble writing a string split function with delimiters. I based my function off of the main function featured here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/.

When I test it via main, I am only able to pass it char[], but not char*. When passing a char*, the program seg faults.

I.e. passing some char str[] through str_split works but not some char* str. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
char** str_split(char* str, const char* delim)
{
  char* tmp;

  char** t = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1024);
  char** tokens = t;

  tmp = strtok(str, delim);

  while(tmp != NULL)
  {
    *tokens = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(tmp));
    *tokens = strdup(tmp);
    tokens++;
    tmp = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }

  return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines gives you two different problems:

```
*tokens = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(tmp));
*tokens = strdup(tmp);
```

The first line will allocate `strlen(tmp)` bytes, but the problem is that strings have an extra character to terminate the string, so you really need to allocate `strlen(tmp) + 1` bytes.

The second line *overwrites* the original pointer you got from `malloc`, causing a memory leak.

Also, in C you [should not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Oh, and another note: `sizeof(char)` is specified to always return `1`, no matter the actual bit-size of the `char` type.

---

As for your seg-faulting, I'm guessing you are calling your function with a string literal, like e.g.

```
some_var = str_split("hello world", " ");
```

Or possibly

```
char *string = "hello world";
some_var = str_split(string, " ");
```

This will cause *undefine behavior*, because string literals are actually a pointer to a *constant* array of characters, and `strtok` *modifies* the string. Undefined behavior is arguably the most common cause of crashes.

If you enable more warnings when building you would have gotten a warning about this, or maybe you *did* get a warning but ignored it, or used casting to get rid of it. Warnings from the compilers are often good indicators of you doing something you should not do, hiding it by e.g. casting will only silent the warning but not fix the problem.

---

There are also a couple of other problems with your code. One is that if there are only one "word"/"token" in the "sentence" you pass in to the function, you waste `4092` or `8184` bytes (depending on 32- or 64-bit platform) in that allocation. You might want to do a separate tokenization loop first (on a temporary copy of the string) first to find out the exact number of "tokens" or "words" in the input.

Doing this counting will also solve the other problem: What if there are *more* than 1024 tokens/words? Your loop will blissfully write out of bounds in that case.

Both of these cases are extremes, and your standard use-case may be a better fit for your current code, but it's still something to think about.

Comment: thank you, this helped. I was able to fix the errors in my program as well as hunt down the memory leaks. I will try and come up with a separate tokenization loop, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

> When I test it via main, I am only able to pass it char[], but not char*. When passing a char*, the program seg faults.

Going by the above chances are that you are not allocating memory for your `char *` in `main` or you are passing a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

you may be assigning value to char * at declaration

```
char *str="abcdef";
```

or you may not have allocated memory to the string pointed by `char * str`. In both of these cases `strtok()` will result in `segmentation fault`.